# Create a class named with a Swift-used name

Tags: swift

I need to call my class `is`, but when I try to do this:

```
class is {

}
```

I get an error:

> Expected identifier in class declaration

Is there a way to bypass this error and call my class `is`? I don't want to call it `IS` or `iss` or `iis` but `is` .

Comment: Why do you want this?  What is your use case?  Sounds like this will cause more confusion for your developers.

Comment: `is` also goes against conventions. Class names should be CamelCased, so `Is` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Furthermore, based on the fact that we can't even guess what you're using this class for tells me that this name isn't nearly as descriptive as it should be.

Comment: Having a class named after a verb is a code smell

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't advise this — it'll certainly make your code much less readable, and there are simple alternatives (such as just using a non-reserved word).

But if you really want, you can write the name as `` `is` ``. Escaping with backticks allows you to use reserved words / keywords as identifiers. You'll have to use the backticks everywhere you want to use the class name:

```
class `is` { }

let obj = `is`()

let objs: [`is`] = []
```

More information can be found in [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html).

Comment: I would add that every usage of that name will also require backticks.

Comment: You forgot to add a really important note: "Don't do this."

Comment: I figured the comments on the question covered that pretty well. But you're right, I'll add it to my answer too.